# How to correctly vertical align image+text inside table cell

Tags: html, css

I need to `vertical-align:top` both 'Some text' and 'Other text'. The following is not working for me, only the second cell is aligned correctly. I don't understand what the problem is.

```
<style>
    td {
      vertical-align:top;
    }
</style>

<table>    
    <tr>
        <td><img src="icon.png"/> Some text </td>
        <td> Other text </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am also working on it but doesn't resolve this problem jsbin link for same          [link](http://jsbin.com/harukomivi/edit?html,css,console,output)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Rather than using:

```
td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Use:

```
td {
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
td img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Then the text in the second cell isn't aligned to the top of the cell.